# Fastest way of plotting a point on screen in MFC C++ app

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, mfc

I have an application that contains many millions of 3d rgb points that form an image when plotted.  What is the fastest way of getting them to screen in a MFC application?  I've tried  CDC.SetPixelV in conjunction with a bitmap, which seems quite slow, and am looking towards a Direct3D or OpenGL window in my MFC view class.  Any other good places to look?

Answer (score 1):

Double buffering is your solution. There are many examples on codeproject. Check [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442/Flicker-free-redrawing-and-background-buffering-of) for example

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a *point cloud*.  You might find some good information searching on that term.

3D hardware is the fastest way to take 3D points and get them into a 2D display, so either Direct3D or OpenGL seem like the obvious choices.

If the number of points is much greater than the number of pixels in your display, then you'll probably first want to cull points that are trivially outside the view.  You put all your points in some sort of spatial partitioning structure (like an octree) and omit the points inside any node that's completely outside the viewing frustrum.  This reduces the amount of data you have to push from system memory to GPU memory, which will likely be the bottleneck.  (If your point cloud is static, and you're just building a fly through, and if your GPU has enough memory, you could skip the culling, send all the data at once, and then just update the transforms for each frame.)

If you don't want to use the GPU and instead write a software renderer, you'll want to render to a bitmap that's in the same pixel format as your display (to eliminate the chance of the blit need to do any pixels formatting as it blasts the bitmap to the display).  For reasonable window sizes, blitting at 30 frames per second is feasible, but it might not leave much time for the CPU to do the rendering.

Comment: Yes, it's a point cloud, and I'm currently looking at PCL and VTK as possible solutions to rendering.  I have a lot of other graphics in addition to the clouds though, and plenty of interaction, so something simpler and lower level (e.g. raw OpenGL) my prove better.